# How to standardize the top margin of Chinese characters across browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, position

I'm developing a website that includes flashcards for learning Chinese characters. The problem is that IE renders fonts slightly higher on the line than do other browsers I've tested. This isn't normally a big deal, but with a flashcard, the font is so big that the difference in placement becomes very noticeable.

I uploaded a dummy version of the webpage here: http://mandaclu.com/dummy/flashcard.html.
Open the link in both Firefox/Chrome and IE to see the difference (To see a really simple page with the same problem, use this link: http://mandaclu.com/dummy/test.html).

I've looked all over and haven't found any way to get that character to sit in the same place on the page regardless of the browser. Does anyone have any ideas? (CSS resets haven't worked either) Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you try a CSS normalize?

Comment: I added that to both pages (flashcard.html and test.html) just now and the placement is still the same.

Comment: Which versions of Firefox/Chrome/IE are you testing with?

Comment: Firefox 25, IE 10, and Chrome 31.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a difference in the way IE and other browsers render text with line-height > text-size.

Try setting line-height = text-size and add a top padding to force the text down instead.

eg.

```
#char {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 180px;
    line-height: 180px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 260px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it didn't work. It just moved the character down 30px in both browsers. So there's still the same difference in positioning.